# Therefore in the middle of a sentence

Tags: adverbs

> Their orientation is ***therefore*** well described by...

Does this use of `therefore` in the middle of the sentence, reduce fluidity or sound not suitable for a written text?

Should I use commas instead?

I am very wary when dealing with such adverbs, because in Italian (my mother tongue) I would insert them almost anywhere in a sentence, without altering the correctness nor the *weirdness*.

Comment: Though there are always style issues, there's nothing fundamentally wrong or alarming with the above usage.

Comment: Could you please expand on the style issues that this use might arouse? Thanks!

Comment: There are others here who excel at expounding on stylistic issues.

Comment: I'm sure that someone will come by to contradict me, but to me, a native speaker, that sounds like the most natural place to put it.

Answer (score -1):

Out of all my years writing, i have never considered this before. "therefore" is usually a word that could be placed in the middle of sentence, but only if included with either a comma or the word "and" in front of it.

here's two examples.

the pen contained a large amount of ink, therefore it lasted for a long time.

the musician got injured and therefore couldn't perform for the concert.

it doesn't interrupt the sentence flow much as long as you use it correctly.

Now that I did more research, I found out that **your usage is actually correct**, it's just a style of wording I have little to no familiarity to.